# How to measure Windows application response times?

Tags: performance, measurement

I'm looking for a solution/software to mimic a regular desktop user and measure how long different operations on a software take. For example, how long it takes to open the software at different times, how long it takes for a program respond when user clicks button A etc. I don't want to get to API/code level. I'd like to set up different tests like "1. open sofware 2. click button A 3. click button B from the opening window and log the execution time".

All questions I found here were related to code-level / server performance measurements.